# Take a look at this icon in Xcode. How can it be disappeared?

Tags: xcode

[image: icon]

I clicked a xib file with mistake. Then I clicked a .m file instantly. It lagged for about 1 second. Then this icon appeared. It's really weird. Anybody have seen this?

Xcode Version 5.1.1 (5B1008)

OSX Yosemite 10.10 beta2

Comment: The picture can now display correctly.

Comment: No, CW. I think it's not a version control Problem.

Comment: Xcode has many many many many many bugs. So clear cache, close, quit and reopen

Comment: What version of Xcode are you using and what OS Version are you running?